Final price in cart page counting tax before applying coupon code
Final Price : 100, so 3 % tax on this 100 = > 103 should be final price, fine.
Now apply coupon code to get 50 % discount , so tax on 50 : 1.5 {3 % }
Issue :
Now Final price is 53 [ 50 + 3 ], it is not calculating tax after applying coupon code.
Result should be 51.5 [ 50 + 1.5 ]

CouponManagement.php :
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Froogal\Cart\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use \Magento\Quote\Api\CouponManagementInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotDeleteException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

/**
 * Coupon management object.
 */
class CouponManagement implements CouponManagementInterface
{
    /**
     * Quote repository.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * Constructs a coupon read service object.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository Quote repository.
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository,
        \Froogal\Magento\Model\LoyaltyCoupons $loyaltyCoupons,
        \Froogal\Magento\Model\Config $config,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteModelRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->loyaltyCoupons = $loyaltyCoupons;
        $this->config = $config;
        $this->quoteModelRepository = $quoteModelRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function get($cartId)
    {
        /** @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $couponCode = $quote->getCouponCode();
        if($couponCode)
        {
            $code = $quote->getCouponCode();
        }
        else
        {
            $code = $quote->getData('loyalty_coupon_code');
        }
        return $code;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function set($cartId, $couponCode)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/cartcoupon.log');
        $logger = new \Zend_Log();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('cart coupon code MODEL');
        
        /** @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        if (!$quote->getItemsCount()) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('The "%1" Cart doesn\'t contain products.', $cartId));
        }
        if (!$quote->getStoreId()) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Cart isn\'t assigned to correct store'));
        }
        

        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);

        try {

            $CouponsModuleEnabled = $this->config->isLoyaltyCouponsModuleEnabled();
            $logger->info('couponModuleEnabled'.$CouponsModuleEnabled.'couponCode'.$couponCode);
        if ($CouponsModuleEnabled) {
        $response = $this->loyaltyCoupons->hold($quote->getId(),$couponCode);
            
        $success = $response["success"] ?? false;
        $logger->info('success'.json_encode($success));
        if($success)
            {
                if ($quote->getData('loyalty_coupon_code') != $couponCode) {
                    throw new NoSuchEntityException(__("The coupon code isn't valid. Verify the code and try again."));
                }
                $quote->setCouponCode($couponCode);
                $this->quoteRepository->save($quote->collectTotals());
                
              
            }
            else
            {
                $errors = $response['errors'] ?? [];
                $status = $errors['status'] ?? '';
                if($status == 'COUPON_NOT_FOUND')
                {
                    $quote->setCouponCode($couponCode);
                    $this->quoteRepository->save($quote->collectTotals());

                  $subtotalWithDiscount = $quote->getData('base_subtotal_with_discount');
                  $calculateTax = $subtotalWithDiscount * 0.03;
                  $grandTotal = $subtotalWithDiscount + $calculateTax;
                  $logger->info('grandTotal'.$grandTotal.'subtotalWithDiscount='.$subtotalWithDiscount.'calculateTax'.$calculateTax);

                  $quote = $this->quoteModelRepository->get($cartId);

                  $quote->setData('grand_total',$grandTotal);
                  $quote->setData('base_grand_total',$grandTotal);
                  $quote->save();
                  $this->quoteRepository->save($quote->collectTotals());

                  $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals();


                  if ($quote->getCouponCode() != $couponCode) {
                    throw new NoSuchEntityException(__("The coupon code isn't valid. Verify the code and try again."));
                }
                
                }
                else
                {
                    $message = $response["message"] ?? 'Something went wrong';
                    throw new NoSuchEntityException(__($message));
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $logger->info('coupon'.$quote->getCouponCode());
            if ($quote->getCouponCode() != $couponCode) {
                throw new NoSuchEntityException(__("The coupon code isn't valid. Verify the code and try again."));
            }
            $quote->setCouponCode($couponCode);
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote->collectTotals());
            

        }


        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $logger->info('error-'.$e->getMessage());
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(__('The coupon code couldn\'t be applied: ' .$e->getMessage()), $e);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new CouldNotSaveException(
                __("The coupon code couldn't be applied. Verify the coupon code and try again."),
                $e
            );
        }
            
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function remove($cartId)
    {
        /** @var  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        if (!$quote->getItemsCount()) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('The "%1" Cart doesn\'t contain products.', $cartId));
        }
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        try {
            $CouponsModuleEnabled = $this->config->isLoyaltyCouponsModuleEnabled();
            if ($CouponsModuleEnabled) {
                $response = $this->loyaltyCoupons->release($quote->getId());
            $success = $response["success"] ?? false;
            if($success)
            {
                $this->quoteRepository->save($quote->collectTotals());
                // return true;
            }
            else
            {
                $errors = $response['errors'] ?? [];
                $status = $errors['status'] ?? 'notFound';
                if($status == 'notFound')
                {
                    $quote->setCouponCode('');
                    $this->quoteRepository->save($quote->collectTotals());
                }
                else
                {
                    $message = $response["message"] ?? 'Something went wrong';
                    throw new NoSuchEntityException(__($message));
                }
            }
            }
            else
            {
                $quote->setCouponCode('');
                $this->quoteRepository->save($quote->collectTotals());
            }
            
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new CouldNotDeleteException(
                __("The coupon code couldn't be deleted. Verify the coupon code and try again.")
            );
        }
        if ($quote->getCouponCode() != '') {
            throw new CouldNotDeleteException(
                __("The coupon code couldn't be deleted. Verify the coupon code and try again.")
            );
        }
        return true;
    }
}


try to set Apply Customer Tax before discount

hi, @Mehran tax is correct only, but  why the final price is calculating tax [ before discount ] ?

Fix on file vendor/magento/module-tax/Model/Calculation/AbstractAggregateCalculator.php:49
Replace:
//TODO: handle originalDiscountAmount
$taxableAmount = max($rowTotalInclTax - $discountAmount, 0);
$rowTaxAfterDiscount = $this->calculationTool->calcTaxAmount(
    $taxableAmount,
    $rate,
    true,
    false
);
$rowTaxAfterDiscount = $this->roundAmount(
    $rowTaxAfterDiscount,
    $rate,
    true,
    self::KEY_REGULAR_DELTA_ROUNDING,
    $round,
    $item
);
// Set discount tax compensation
$discountTaxCompensationAmount = $rowTax - $rowTaxAfterDiscount;
$rowTax = $rowTaxAfterDiscount;

With the following:
$taxableAmount = max($rowTotal - $discountAmount, 0);
$discountTaxCompensationAmount = 0;
$rowTax = $taxableAmount * ($rate / 100);


Changing a code in vendor is never suggested. You can create plugin
for public method or override method in your custom module.

Reference : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/29506
